# How can I combine multiple if conditions to create a new column and add or subtract from the previous row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new column in my data frame with multiple if conditions and either add value or subtract a value from the previous row depending on the conditions.

I tried using a lambda function but I am pretty certain the syntax is wrong. So I have not really any idea to solve my problem. As `df['b']` this is just a dummy variable to test the lambda function instead of `df['a']`.

Maybe an equation: `a_i = 1t* 40 + a0` until 620 , after is reached T = 620 is goes down one Rate of `a _i = a_i-1 -1t+40`.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'t' : [0, 8,32, 56, 96, 128],
               'T' : [460, 500, 620, 500, 300, 460],
              })
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'t' : [0, 8,32, 56, 96, 128],
               'T' : [460, 500, 620, 500, 300, 460],
               'a' : [10000, 10320, 11280, 10320, 8720, 10000]})

print (df)

df.loc[0,'a']=10000
df['a']= df['t']*5+ df.loc[0,'a']

df.loc[0,'b']=100
df['b'] = df['T'].apply(lambda x: df['t']*5+ df.loc[0,'b'] if x <= 500 
df['t']*5+ df.loc[0,'b'] if x <= 620 
-df['t']*5+ df.loc[0,'b'] if x <= 300 )


#df.loc[0,'i']=50
#df['i'] = [5+ df.loc[0,'i'] for x in range(df.shape[0])]

print(df)

print(df1)
```

I wanted to create something like this:

```
     t    T      a
0    0  460  10000
1    8  500  10320
2   32  620  11280
3   56  500  10320
4   96  300   8720
5  128  460  10000
```

Comment: I am reading this as `df1` is what you are hoping to get and `df` are your inputs- and you are using rows `T` and `t` to solve for the values in `a`? What is the equation that takes `T` and `t` and gives you `a`? the code you wrote is not very clear

Comment: Yes df1 is the outcome I wish. As mentioned a grows with t as in time, for one 1 t it grows 40 but only until it reached 620 than is goes down in a rate for 40 per 1t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reference multiple columns with `apply`, you have to write your function for a full row and apply it to the full data frame. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    't' : [0, 8,32, 56, 96, 128],
    'T' : [460, 500, 620, 500, 300, 460],
})

def a(row):
    a_0 = 10000
    return a_0 + row['t'] + row['T']

df['a'] = df.apply(a, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Which prints:

```
     t    T      a
0    0  460  10460
1    8  500  10508
2   32  620  10652
3   56  500  10556
4   96  300  10396
5  128  460  10588
```

It's not a solution to your question, but you can see that values from both `row['t']` and `row['T']` are accessible.

However, in your case, I think you'd better just use a for loop until `620` is reached and then another for loop for the remaining rows:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    't' : [0, 8,32, 56, 96, 128],
    'T' : [460, 500, 620, 500, 300, 460],
})

a_0 = 10000
for i in range(len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'a'] = df['t'][i] * 40 + a_0
    if df['T'][i] == 620:
        break

for i in range(i + 1, len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'a'] = df['a'][i - 1] - (df['t'][i] - df['t'][i - 1]) * 40
    if df['T'][i] == 300:
        break

for i in range(i + 1, len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'a'] = df['a'][i - 1] + (df['t'][i] - df['t'][i - 1]) * 40
    if df['T'][i] == 460:
        break

print(df)
```

Which prints:

```
     t    T        a
0    0  460  10000.0
1    8  500  10320.0
2   32  620  11280.0
3   56  500  10320.0
4   96  300   8720.0
5  128  460  10000.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this a great first step.  As you already mentioned my equation is not quite accurate.

Comment: So now with the right equation, it got the result that I wanted. Again Thank you.